# Setting the value of a MUI file TextField causes an exception

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I"m trying to set the value of a MUI Textfield that has `type="file"` props, 
and this exception appears in the console: 
`Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` 
Only an empty string doesn't causing this exception.

Here is my component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setImage(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      helperText="Cover photo"
      type="file"
      value={image}
      onChange={handleImageChange}
    />
  );
};
```

I tried to simplify the component (still same exception):

```
<TextField type="file" value={"https://www.someSite.com/image.jpg"} />
```

Also, I tried to set the value of the input itself using `InputProps`, still the same exception.

According to MUI Docs `value` could be 'any' regardless the `type`:
[image: MUI Docs]

Comment: Maybe this link has your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589302/how-to-enable-file-upload-on-reacts-material-ui-simple-input

Comment: I saw this one before I posted my question, but the solutions they offered are different from what I"m trying to do: to upload an image and display the url as string - the same functionality as a regular HTML input

Comment: I'l try to create an example in code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for your problem would be this:

You are trying to set a string in an input file, I will explain next steps to solve this

- Create an input file hidden and his `ref`
- Add an icon inside `InputProps` from your main `TextField`
- Add `onClick` to this icon to call refs input to pop up to choose file
- Add `onChange` to input file to call your previous method created (handleImageChange)
- Assign value `image` string to main `TextField`

This is an example code that works:

```js
export default function App() {
  const inputFileRef = useRef(null)
  const [image, setImage] = useState("")
  const handleClickInputFile = () => {
    inputFileRef.current.click()
  }

  const handleChangeInputFile = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setImage(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField value={image} onChange={(event => setImage(event.target.value))} multiline fullWidth  InputProps={{
            endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start" onClick={handleClickInputFile} style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Click</InputAdornment>,
          }}/>
      <input type="file" ref={inputFileRef} onChange={handleChangeInputFile} style={{display:"none"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now you can change the `click` text by an icon from mui and that's it!

You can check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-vp3nds?file=/src/App.js) to see the final solution works

Let me know if you have any problem